# How can I filter special characters and spaces from my name input fields in react?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-router, react-props, regexp-replace

I wish to share this code just in case someone might need to solve such a problem of filtering unwanted characters when doing forms in react. For extras, my code shows how to pass props to components inside Route. For simplicity, I have focused on only these two inputs and omitted other stuff such as the submit button and css data for styling those classNames and ids.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import SignupForm from "./components/SignupForm";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
    };
    //Binding this to the functions used as they wouldn't just work if not bound
    this.changeFirstName = this.changeFirstName.bind(this);
    this.changeLastName = this.changeLastName.bind(this);
    this.lettersOnly = this.lettersOnly.bind(this);
  }

  changeFirstName(e) {
    this.setState({ firstName: e.target.value });
  }

  changeLastName(e) {
    this.setState({ lastName: e.target.value });
  }

  // Error handler functions

  lettersOnly(nameInput) {//Replacing all characters except a-z by nothing with this function
    let regex = /[^a-z]/gi; 
    nameInput.target.value = nameInput.target.value.replace(regex, "");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            comp={SignupForm}
            render={() => (
              <SignupForm

                //SignupForm submit props
                changeFirstNameHandler={this.changeFirstName}
                firstNameValue={this.state.firstName}
                changeLastNameHandler={this.changeLastName}
                lastNameValue={this.state.lastName}

                // Error handlers
                nameCharacterFilter={this.lettersOnly}
              />
            )}
          />
            )}
          />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Below is the signup form, which is the child component in this aspect, and also a function component as opposed to its parent component:

```
import React from "react";

export default function SignupForm(props) {
  return (
    <div className="container" id="signupForm">
      <h1>Signup Form</h1>
      <div className="form-div">
        <form>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="First Name"
            onChange={props.changeFirstNameHandler}
            value={props.firstNameValue}
            onKeyUp={props.nameCharacterFilter}
            className="form-control formgroup"
          />

          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Last Name"
            onChange={props.changeLastNameHandler}
            value={props.lastNameValue}
            onKeyUp={props.nameCharacterFilter}
            className="form-control formgroup"
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**NB: Welcome to improve this code, if you feel the need!**

Answer (score 1):

I think you can improve you're code with this changes:

- Use the regex directly in the onChange event
- Use only one method to update the values

Here is an example of what I mean: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-vreku?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Regards!

Comment: Cheers @the_previ! I will do just that. Kindly give a vote up if you feel my code is adding some value to this platform.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is an improved code and much more cleaner. However, I have just omitted the React Router part to focus on functionality of the state and functions in this case.
I also want the user to see when they type an unwanted character that it actually typed but then just deleted on key up so I have created an independent function `justLettersAndHyphen(nameField)` from `changeValue(event)` that is triggered by `onKeyUp`.

```
import React from "react";
import SignupForm from "./SignupForm";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: ""
    };

    this.changeValue = this.changeValue.bind(this);
    this.justLettersAndHyphen = this.justLettersAndHyphen.bind(this);
  }

  changeValue(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  // Error handler functions

  justLettersAndHyphen(nameField) {
    let regex = /[^a-z-]/gi;
    nameField.target.value = nameField.target.value.replace(regex, "");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SignupForm
        firstNameValue={this.state.firstName}
        lastNameValue={this.state.lastName}
        changeValueHandler={this.changeValue}
        nameCharacterFilter={this.justLettersAndHyphen}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Child component edited with name property added.

```
import React from "react";

export default function SignupForm(props) {
  return (
    <div className="container" id="signupForm">
      <h1>Signup Form</h1>
      <div className="form-div">
        <form>
          <input
            name="firstName"
            type="text"
            placeholder="First Name"
            onChange={props.changeValueHandler}
            onKeyUp={props.nameCharacterFilter}
            value={props.firstNameValue}
          />

          <input
            name="lastName"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Last Name"
            onChange={props.changeValueHandler}
            onKeyUp={props.nameCharacterFilter}
            value={props.lastNameValue}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```